# How to determine if an ASP.NET site has a memory leak

Tags: asp.net, memory-leaks

Without using any third-party tools, how can you determine if an ASP.NET application (.NET 3.5) has any memory leaks?  I want to make sure that an app that was developed by someone else is running okay.  I would assume using performance counters but which one(s) are the right ones to use to see if the app has memory leaks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use:

[Debug Diagnostic Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=28BD5941-C458-46F1-B24D-F60151D875A3&displaylang=en)

Description from Microsoft website:

> The Debug Diagnostic Tool (DebugDiag)
>   is designed to assist in
>   troubleshooting issues such as hangs,
>   slow performance, **memory leaks or
>   fragmentation**, and crashes in any
>   user-mode process. The tool includes
>   additional debugging scripts focused
>   on Internet Information Services (IIS)
>   applications, web data access
>   components, COM+ and related Microsoft
>   technologies.

Free download and instructions on how to use it are all located on the [linked page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=28BD5941-C458-46F1-B24D-F60151D875A3&displaylang=en).

This link might also be of use:

[How to use the IIS Debug Diagnostics tool to troubleshoot a memory leak in an IIS process](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919790/)

Answer (score 1):

The [CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx) (see the section "Identifying Where Your Application Allocates Memory").

Answer (score 1):

If you want to really learn how to use [Debug Diagnostic Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=28BD5941-C458-46F1-B24D-F60151D875A3&displaylang=en) you should read [Tess Ferrandes blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tess/), she is an ASP.Net escalation engineer and writes useful articles about how to diagnose common issues in ASP.Net applications with those tools.

Hope it helps!!!